# C code : Calling function in main

Tags: c, unix, gcc

I have two programs which I have written in C code both of them have main function (I was not able to run the program without main function) now I want to create a single main file say main.c from where I can call these two functions. How can I do that ? Please suggest .. I am relatively very new to c programming.

**Rk4solution.c**

```
#define beginrk4 main
 int func (double t, const double y[], double f[], void *params)
 {}
int beginrk4 () /*** main function ***/
```

**Rk8pdsolution.c**

```
#define beginrk8pd main
int func (double t, const double y[], double f[], void *params)
{}
int beginrk8pd () /*** main function ****/
```

How to create a main function to call these two?

Comment: What is the sequence? how you want these functions to be called?

Comment: 2.  SO is not substitute for leaning to program

Comment: @SouravGhosh : Sequence is not important .. I have created these to solve second order differential equation using GSL lib.

Comment: You seem to have a global function called `func()` in each source file, and also a pair of function names `beginrk4` and `beginrk8pd` that you map to `main()`.  That's two conflicts — two `func()` and two `main()`.  You need to give each `func()` its own name, and suppress the `main()` functions in the individual files.  You end up with two source files, one for `rk4` and one for `rk8pd`, and two (or possibly one) header(s) for declaring the functions.  You then write a `main()` function in a third source file that calls the other functions, including the header(s) to declare the functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks . Still getting the error main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `beginrk4'

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Do I need to give specific file name through gcc? gcc  -I$TACC_GSL_INC -I$TACC_GRVY_INC -L$TACC_GRVY_LIB -L$TACC_GSL_LIB -lgsl -lgslcblas -lgrvy main.c

Comment: Yes; if you have three source files: `main.c`, `rk4.c` and `rk8pd.c`, then you have various options, but `gcc -o rk main.c rk4.c rk8pd.c -lm` would probably produce you a runnable program as long as `main()` and `func()` aren't repeated.  And list libraries after source and/or object files.  Always!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Thank you .. it worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into answer.*</sup>

You seem to have a global function called `func()` in each source file, and also a pair of function names `beginrk4` and `beginrk8pd` that you map to `main()`. That's two conflicts — two `func()` and two `main()`.

You need to give each `func()` its own name, and suppress the `main()` functions in the individual files. You end up with two source files, one for `rk4` (e.g. `rk4.c`) and one for `rk8pd` (`rk8pd.c`), and two headers (`rk4.h` and rk8pd.h`) — or possibly one header`rk.h`— for declaring the functions. You then write a`main()`function in a third source file (`main.c`) that calls the other functions, and includes the header(s) to declare the functions.

> Still getting the error `` main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `beginrk4' ``
>
> Do I need to give specific file name through gcc?
>
> ```
> gcc -I$TACC_GSL_INC -I$TACC_GRVY_INC -L$TACC_GRVY_LIB -L$TACC_GSL_LIB -lgsl -lgslcblas -lgrvy main.c
> ```

Yes; if you have three source files: `main.c`, `rk4.c` and `rk8pd.c`, then you have various options, but

```
gcc -o rk main.c rk4.c rk8pd.c -lm
```

would probably produce you a runnable program as long as `main()` and `func()` aren't repeated. Always list libraries (`-lxyz`) after source and/or object files. Always!